# Deploying Rails app requires Apache restart to show changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm deploying a Rails 4.2.1 app to an Apache / Passenger server with Capistrano 3.4.0.

The trouble is, when I do `cap production deploy`, no changes appear until I restart Apache.

Why is that? Does this have to do with my not having a tmp/restart.txt file in my app directory? (I seem to remember that was required for previous Rails versions)

Everything else works fine, as in `cap production deploy` updates the `current` directory of the app on the server. There are no errors in the capistrano deploy log.

Comment: Do you have the `capistrano-passenger` gem installed and is it required in your Capfile?

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify passenger to reload (redeploy) application. One way of doing it is by touching `tmp/restart.txt` file.

You can also use [`capistrano-passanger` GEM](https://github.com/capistrano/passenger/) capistrano can take care of that for you. It is also doing it more effectively by using `passenger-config restart-app` command for passanger >= 5.